# How to create a multiple column Excel table from single column of string data that automatically adds rows when new rows are added to data?

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple rows of single string data on sheet1 that I have used the MID formula to separate into multiple columns on sheet2; if I add new rows of string data to sheet1, how can I automate the same MID formula to be added to each column for each added row?

Here is an example of what these two sheets currently look like:

[sheet1] - string data

1239876010407201520.00

4566543010407201550.00

7893210010407201560.00

sheet2

Number  User    Type    Date    Amount

123 9876    1   4/7/2015     $20.00

456 6543    1   4/7/2015     $50.00

789 3210    1   4/7/2015     $60.00

If I add a row of string data to sheet1 how can I have Excel automatically add a row and apply the same MID formula to each table column on sheet2?

Comment: If that date *mm/dd/yyyy* or *dd/mm/yyyy*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the Sheet1's name tab and choose **View Code**. When the VBE opens up, paste the following into the code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range, str As String, rw As Long
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns(1))
            str = rng.Value
            If Len(str) >= 18 Then
                With Sheet2 'using sheet codename in case it gets reordered or renamed
                    rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    .Cells(rw, 1) = Left(str, 3)
                    .Cells(rw, 2) = Mid(str, 4, 4)
                    .Cells(rw, 3) = Mid(str, 8, 2)
                    .Cells(rw, 4) = DateSerial(Mid(str, 14, 4), Mid(str, 10, 2), Mid(str, 12, 2))
                    .Cells(rw, 5) = CCur(Mid(str, 18, 99))
                End With
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Any values typed or pasted into column A will be stripped and split down to 5 values and populated into Sheet2's first available row in columns A:E. I've set a minimum length of 18 characters before it will attempt processing. This length amounts to a single digit being supplied for the amount off the right-hand end after the year.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your mid formula in an iferror formula and set it to blank if it is an error, then just drag it down a bunch of rows and where there is data it will resolve, where there is not it will simply be blank giving the impression there is nothing there.

If you post your original mid formula I will give you an example, it may be prudent to test the cell rather than using iferror as iferror will trap genuine errors.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will automatically fill the rows that are not blank so I do not have to drag it down manually.